# Showing the energy of Dirichlet problem is lower semicontinuous.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I am proving the existence of minimizers in $H_0^1(\Omega)$ of $$E[u] = \int |\nabla u|^2 -\int fu.$$

After showing that it is bounded, we pick a minimizing sequence $u_k \rightarrow u$ weakly in $H_0^1(\Omega)$ and stronlgy in $L^2(\Omega)$. Now I need to claim that $$E[u]\leq \liminf E[u_k].$$

This is the fact that $E$ is lower semicontinuous, but I am stuck at showing this directly. By weak convergence, we have:
$$\int |\nabla u||\nabla u_k| +\int u u_k \rightarrow \int |\nabla u|^2 +\int u^2.$$
And by $L^2$ convergence, the second term converges, so
$$\int |\nabla u||\nabla u_k|\rightarrow \int |\nabla u|^2 .$$

How do we go from here to prove the lower semicontinuity?

Comment: I'm not putting this in an answer as I'm not answering your question directly (i.e. I'm not showing $E$ is LSC), but I think you can show $a(u, v) = \int \nabla u \cdot \nabla v$ is a continuous, coercive bilinear form and then use Lax-Milgram to show the existence of the minimizer.

Comment: A rather standard method for establishing weak lower-semicontinuity (on appropriate Sobolev spaces) is proving convexity of the integrand $I$ with respect to the gradient variable, i.e., $b\mapsto I(x, a, b)$ with $I = I(x, u(x), \nabla u(x))$.

Comment: You can use the general claim that convex and continuous functions are weakly lower semicontinuous.

Answer (score 1):

The claim
$$
\int_\Omega |\nabla u_k| \cdot |\nabla u| \to \int |\nabla u|^2
$$
is *wrong*. Another line to argue lower semicontinuity is to recognize that $u\mapsto \int |\nabla u|^2$ is a norm on $H^1_0$, and norms are weakly lower semicontinuous.

Answer (score 0):

Since $u_k \rightarrow u$ weakly, we have:
\begin{equation}
\int|\nabla u_k||\nabla u| + \int u_k u \rightarrow \int |\nabla u|^2 + \int u^2.
\end{equation}
The second term converges by strong $L^2$ convergence, so we have:
\begin{equation}
\|\nabla u\|^2_{L^2} =\int|\nabla u|^2 \leq \liminf \int |\nabla u_k||\nabla u| \leq \liminf \|\nabla u_k\|_{L^2}\|\nabla u\|_{L^2}
\end{equation}
Dividing both sides by $\|\nabla u\|_{L^2}$ gives $\|\nabla u\|_{L^2} \leq \liminf\|\nabla u_k\|_{L^2}$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
E[u] = \frac{1}{2}\int |\nabla u|^2 - \int uf
\leq \liminf \frac{1}{2} \int |\nabla u_k|^2 - \int u_kf = \liminf E[u_k]
\end{align}

Comment: This reasoning is wrong. The weak convergence does not imply the convergence in the first integral. In particular, $|\nabla u_k|$ does not converge in any sense to $|\nabla u|$ in general.